# How to BOLD specific text when fetching from a database

Tags: android

I have a external database. I want to **BOLD** some specific texts. For example I have one column with **Word** name , and another column with **Example** . Each word have one example , in each example , use word.

For example : word is **afraid** .

example is : The girl **afraid** of what she saw.

I want when fetch data and show in recylerview , bold words inside example .

I use below code for reaching that, but doesn't work and specific text don't bold it.

```
String bolder = holder.title.getText().toString();

SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(bolder);
stringBuilder.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0,
                holder.title.getText().toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Log.d("span",holder.title.getText().toString());

holder.example.setText(stringBuilder);
holder.example.setText(wordsList.getExample());
```

I know , with html tag like  we can bolded , but my data is more , and I want use Spannable .

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, in detail, what "doesn't work" means. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/RichText/Search) shows how to use `SpannableStringBuilder` to highlight words in a longer string (though I use a background color rather than bold).

Comment: I'd simply save the text in HTML stle (i.e.: `The girl is <b>afraid</b>`). And then use the (deprecated?) `HTML.frmHtml()` method to display it.

Comment: @CommonsWare question is simple. I want to bold specific  text. But my code doesn't work.

Comment: @ModularSynth Thanks, but I say my data is huge , and I can't do this for all data, because of this I want to bold with SpannableStringBuilder .

Comment: Why are you changing the content of `holder.example` right after you use your `stringBuilder`? if you do that the span you added won't show

Comment: Then another chance would be to have a list of words and replace those words by appending the `<b>` and `</b>` tags.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, in detail, what "specific text don't bold it" means. After all, you are not using the results of the `stringBuilder`. You make the text bold, put that `stringBuilder` in the `example`, then replace that text with something else before displaying it.

Comment: Your code to bold the text `holder.example.setText(stringBuilder);` gets replaced by the next line `holder.example.setText(wordsList.getExample());` . remove the last line from your code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Your code to bold the text

> holder.example.setText(stringBuilder);

gets replaced by the next line

> holder.example.setText(wordsList.getExample());

So, remove the last line from your code.

If you have idea of the word that you want to bold, then you need to find the position of that word in the text you get from external database and accordingly you will require to use spannable to bold that word.

For example :

```
    String wordToBold= "afraid"; // the word that you want to bold out

    String textFromDatabase = wordsList.getExample();
    SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(textFromDatabase);
    int startPosition= textFromDatabase.indexOf(wordToBold);
    if(startPosition!=-1){
           stringBuilder.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startPosition, startPosition + wordToBold.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
           holder.example.setText(stringBuilder);
    }
    else{
           holder.example.setText(wordsList.getExample());
    }
```

Hope it will help you ツ

Comment: Thanks bro for reply, I use above code , but app crashed and error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (10 ... 6) has end before start` is print in logcat. When  scroll slow , I see bold words don't apply, and after this app crashed.

Comment: You need to put this block in try catch block. print the startPosition in the log and check whether it gives the correct position or not.

Comment: Why you suggest use try catch bro ? Also I SAY, bold afraid don't apply it. I don't know why, because you'r code is correct , because start position correct and end .

Comment: can you please debug the code and check where the app crashes?

Comment: Yeah I found the mistake.. replace  wordToBold.length() with startPosition+ wordToBold.length().

Comment: I am able to bold the word with this changes.

Comment: Thanks dear, finally worked. I search a lot about this question, but nothing work for me. Thanks again bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

**1. use `setTypeface`**

```
holder.example.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
```

**2.use `getPaint`**

```
holder.example.getPaint().setFakeBoldText(true);
```

**Edit**

```
String bolder = holder.title.getText().toString();
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(bolder + wordsList.getExample());
StyleSpan span = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
stringBuilder.setSpan(span, 0, bolder.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Log.d("span", holder.title.getText().toString());
holder.example.setText(stringBuilder);
```

Comment: I don't want this bro, this code apply bold for all statement. I want just bold words like question example .

Comment: Thanks bro, but this code make a statement with word at first and example + on it. like : afraidThe women was afraid of what shw saw.

Comment: I think my problem is when start bold and end bold it.  I MUST use int start and int end right ?

Comment: YES . You must know about it .

Comment: I means , because int start and int end is wrong, afraid don't bold it.

Comment: You must know correct start index and correct end index .